# SQL Query with a list

Tags: c#, sql, list

I have the code structured as follows.

```
public class A 
{
   public Guid AId { get; set; }
   public List<B> Blist { get; set; }
}

public class B 
{
   public Guid BId { get; set; }
   public Guid AId { get; set; }
   public int type { get; set; }
}
```

That is, entity A has multiple entities B in the database.

I would like to do a query that gives a list of types:

1. If the list is empty, the query returns all elements from table A.
2. If there is any element in the list, the query must return which are the "A" entities, which have at least one entity B with one of the types belonging to the list.

The query number two would be something like that:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A 
JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT type, AId 
     FROM B) b ON A.AId = b.AId 
               AND t.type IN (SELECT Value FROM @types)
```

I don't know how to join the two conditions in a query

Comment: Table definitions, sample data and desired results would be beneficial as would a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How about `(SELECT A.* FROM A WHERE @types IS NULL) UNION ALL (what you have above)` ?